# Transformers: ResourceExhaustedError: failed to allocate memory [Op:AddV2]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, out-of-memory, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use a text generation model using the transformers library. I am specifically following a tutorial from [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate), but I am running into a memory issue.

**The Problem:**

The issue arises when downloading the model:

```
model = TFGPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2", pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: failed to allocate memory [Op:AddV2]
```

**What I tried:**

I ran this using two databricks clusters (One more CPU, another more GPU). To make sure the GPU was available, i used the following command:

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Output:

```
True
```

To check the NVIDIA-SMI, I ran the following:

```
!nvidia-smi
```

Output:

```
Fri Sep 24 18:11:37 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  Off  | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0   172W / 300W |  16140MiB / 16160MiB |     73%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In addition to checking the memory, I also tried a few other 'lighter' models instead of "gpt2" such as "distilgpt2".

**What I am asking:**

I understand that it is running out of memory. What I do not know is what is why or what to do next.

I do not know enough about memory, GPUs, and CPUs as they relate to deep learning models. Any guidance on what I can do to fix this, or what I can check next would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is someone else using your GPU? 16140 MiB are already allocated.